# Sparklyr Error in as.character(call[[1]]) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, sparklyr

Trying to figure out what this error means and how to resolve it. I'm using sparklyr with Spark 3.0 for a multi-classification problem using random forest.  My data looks like this prior to feature engineering:

The data is about 1 million rows:

```
 Source: spark<?> [?? x 8]
   label_detail duration orig_bytes resp_bytes proto history time_diff_from_last_connection resp_class
   <chr>           <dbl>      <int>      <int> <chr> <chr>                            <dbl> <chr>     
 1 okiru               0          0          0 tcp   S                             0.000250 A         
 2 okiru               0          0          0 tcp   S                             0.000250 B         
 3 okiru               0          0          0 tcp   S                             0.000250 C         
 4 okiru               0          0          0 tcp   S                             0.000250 A         
 5 okiru               0          0          0 tcp   S                             0.000250 B
```

I then use the ml pipeline as follows:

```
pipline <- ml_pipeline(sc) %>% 
  ft_string_indexer("label_detail", "label_detail_idx") %>% 
  ft_string_indexer("proto", "proto_idx") %>% 
  ft_string_indexer("resp_class", "resp_class_idx") %>% 
  ft_one_hot_encoder(
    input_cols = c( "proto_idx", "resp_class_idx"),
    output_cols = c( "proto_encode", "resp_class_encode")) %>%
  ft_regex_tokenizer("history", "history_token", pattern = "") %>% 
  ft_count_vectorizer(input_col = "history_token", output_col = "history_vector") %>% 
  ft_vector_assembler(
    input_cols = c("duration", "orig_bytes", 
                   "resp_bytes", "proto_encode", "time_diff_from_last_connection", "resp_class_encode", "history_vector"), 
    output_col = "features") %>% 
  ml_random_forest_classifier(label_col="label_detail_idx",
                              features_col="features",
                              seed=222)

model_rf<-ml_fit(pipline,zeek_train)
```

when running `ml_fit` I get the following error:

```
> model_rf<-ml_fit(pipline,zeek_train)
Error in as.character(call[[1]]) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

I also get the same error when using the data and example from https://therinspark.com/pipelines.html  Mastering Spark with R

```
okc_train <- spark_read_parquet(sc, "data/okc-train.parquet")

okc_train <- okc_train %>% 
  select(not_working, age, sex, drinks, drugs, essay1:essay9, essay_length)

pipeline <- ml_pipeline(sc) %>%
  ft_string_indexer(input_col = "sex", output_col = "sex_indexed") %>%
  ft_string_indexer(input_col = "drinks", output_col = "drinks_indexed") %>%
  ft_string_indexer(input_col = "drugs", output_col = "drugs_indexed") %>%
  ft_one_hot_encoder(
    input_cols = c("sex_indexed", "drinks_indexed", "drugs_indexed"),
    output_cols = c("sex_encoded", "drinks_encoded", "drugs_encoded")
  ) %>%
  ft_vector_assembler(
    input_cols = c("age", "sex_encoded", "drinks_encoded", 
                   "drugs_encoded", "essay_length"), 
    output_col = "features"
  ) %>%
  ft_standard_scaler(input_col = "features", output_col = "features_scaled", 
                     with_mean = TRUE) %>%
  ml_logistic_regression(features_col = "features_scaled", 
                         label_col = "not_working")


 ml_fit(pipeline, okc_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with the book example, so I used traceback() after the error message to figure out more details. It looks like the feature requires the Spark 3.0 version.

Comment: I believe I'm also using Spark 3.0, I will check to see what spark engine is being called.